# What is the correct way to write HTML using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, code-generation, document.write

It seems that experienced web developers frown upon using `document.write()` in JavaScript when writing dynamic HTML.

Why is this? and what is the *correct* way?

Comment: JQuery.  I didn't add this as an actual answer, but I came close.  It handles dom manipulation properly, while letting you write something simple like this: $("<div><span>text</span><div>sub</div></div>").appendTo('body');

Comment: This is a case where the jQuery meme actually makes sense.  "I see you're trying to write HTML using JavaScript.  You should totally drop that and use jQuery!"

Comment: jQuery is by no means the "correct" way to create HTML in JavaScript. It is written in JavaScript and will use one or more of the methods in the answers below, with the disadvantage that as a general purpose library it will not be making the informed choices of strategy for each situation that you as a developer would have.

Comment: @Tim: It is no more "correct" or "incorrect" than any of the methods given, but it is a perfectly valid approach.  There is no one answer that is "correct" in all situations.  Your given "disadvantage" is merely a characteristic:  I may or may not to spend my time analyzing optimal strategies for HTML production when the potential benefits are marginal.  Depending on your choice, transparently managing that complexity could be an advantage or a disadvantage.  One may decide to use jQuery until and unless there is a need for a more optimal strategy.

Comment: @Adam - Well argued. "disadvantage" is still accurate in terms of writing the most efficient code but I take your point that the gain in efficiency will not always be important enough to outweigh the convenience of jQuery's method, if and only if jQuery is already being used for another non-trivial task on the page. It's certainly not a job worth using jQuery for on its own.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

`document.write()` will only work while the page is being originally parsed and the DOM is being created. Once the browser gets to the closing `</body>` tag and the DOM is ready, you can't use `document.write()` anymore.

I wouldn't say using `document.write()` is correct or incorrect, it just depends on your situation. In some cases you just need to have `document.write()` to accomplish the task. Look at how Google analytics gets injected into most websites.

After DOM ready, you have two ways to insert dynamic HTML (assuming we are going to insert new HTML into `<div id="node-id"></div>`):

1. Using innerHTML on a node:

   ```
   var node = document.getElementById('node-id');
   node.innerHTML('<p>some dynamic html</p>');
   ```
2. Using DOM methods:

   ```
   var node = document.getElementById('node-id');
   var newNode = document.createElement('p');
   newNode.appendChild(document.createTextNode('some dynamic html'));
   node.appendChild(newNode);
   ```

Using the DOM API methods might be the purist way to do stuff, but `innerHTML` has been proven to be much faster and is used under the hood in JavaScript libraries such as jQuery.

**Note:** The `<script>` will have to be inside your `<body>` tag for this to work.

Comment: You can use it, try it =). It's probably not what you want to do, but still you can.

Comment: A nice full answer, thankyou. I understand now that document.write() only is useful for when the page is loading and being created for the first time. For dynamically updating the page afterwards the DOM methods or innerHTML() are a must.

Comment: Could you provide proof that innerHTML is always faster? I would doubt it's always the case. If you add nodes one at a time to an existing node in the DOM then I expect innerHTML is faster, since the browser potentially has to manipulate and re-render parts of the document at every stage, but if instead you create a new node tree and add its root node to the DOM at the end, I would expect that to be as fast or faster than using innerHTML.

Comment: @Maiku - LOL, true that :)

@Tim - Here is a benchmark http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/innerhtml.html

And actually, using document fragments seems to be the fastest : http://ejohn.org/blog/dom-documentfragments/

Comment: @Ricky - thanks, interesting reading. Both linked articles are flawed: the quirksmode example is quite old, so is not tested against the most recent major version of any of the browsers and in IE's case the last two major versions (note that he tested against IE7 beta 3, not the final release). However, it does prove your point for IE6 and his example. John Resig's example, on the other hand, is extremely flawed and proves nothing, as the comments for the article show.

Comment: @Tim - This day in age, I think we should just trust the frameworks to do this low level DOM stuff for us. Hopefully, they know more than we do :)

Comment: @Ricky - I've looked in depth at the code for some of these libraries and I wouldn't be so sure.

Comment: `node.innerHTML = '<p>some dynamic html</p>';` ? At least on WebView on Android innerHTML is not a function.

Comment: Firefox doesn't support innerHTML nor outerHTML.

Comment: var node = document.getElementById('node-id');
node.innerHTML('<p>some dynamic html</p>');
This does not work for me, 
I used document.getElementById("node-id").innerHTML = "<p>some dynamic html</p>";  (firefox)

Comment: @domen it's certainly because your element doesn't exsite when you call innerHTML. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10826756/javascript-innerhtml-not-working

Comment: According to my browser, node.innerHTML('<p>some dynamic html</p>') is not a function and needs to be written as node.innerHTML = '<p>some dynamic html</p>'

Answer (score 28):

`document.write()` doesn't work with XHTML. It's executed *after* the page has finished loading and does nothing more than write out a string of HTML.

Since the actual in-memory representation of HTML is the DOM, the best way to update a given page is to manipulate the DOM directly.

The way you'd go about doing this would be to programmatically create your nodes and then attach them to an existing place in the DOM. For [purposes of a contrived] example, assuming that I've got a `div` element maintaining an `ID` attribute of "header," then I could introduce some dynamic text by doing this:

```
// create my text
var sHeader = document.createTextNode('Hello world!');

// create an element for the text and append it
var spanHeader = document.createElement('span');
spanHeader.appendChild(sHeader);

// grab a reference to the div header
var divHeader = document.getElementById('header');

// append the new element to the header
divHeader.appendChild(spanHeader);
```

Comment: It's actually executed when you call it. If you call it after the page has loaded it will overwrite the content.

Comment: Stick to HTML and `document.write` remains a useful tool.

Answer (score 10):

1. DOM methods, as outlined by Tom.
2. innerHTML, as mentioned by iHunger.

DOM methods are highly preferable to strings for setting attributes and content. If you ever find yourself writing `innerHTML= '<a href="'+path+'">'+text+'</a>'` you're actually creating new cross-site-scripting security holes on the client side, which is a bit sad if you've spent any time securing your server-side.

DOM methods are traditionally described as ‘slow’ compared to innerHTML. But this isn't really the whole story. What is slow is inserting a lot of child nodes:

```
 for (var i= 0; i<1000; i++)
     div.parentNode.insertBefore(document.createElement('div'), div);
```

This translates to a load of work for the DOM finding the right place in its nodelist to insert the element, moving the other child nodes up, inserting the new node, updating the pointers, and so on.

Setting an existing attribute's value, or a text node's data, on the other hand, is very fast; you just change a string pointer and that's it. This is going to be much faster than serialising the parent with innerHTML, changing it, and parsing it back in (and won't lose your unserialisable data like event handlers, JS references and form values).

There are techniques to do DOM manipulations without so much slow childNodes walking. In particular, be aware of the possibilities of `cloneNode`, and using `DocumentFragment`. But sometimes innerHTML really is quicker. You can still get the best of both worlds by using innerHTML to write your basic structure with placeholders for attribute values and text content, which you then fill in afterwards using DOM. This saves you having to write your own `escapehtml()` function to get around the escaping/security problems mentioned above.

Answer (score 9):

Perhaps a good idea is to use jQuery in this case. It provides handy functionality and you can do things like this:

```
$('div').html('<b>Test</b>');
```

Take a look at http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/html#val for more information.

Comment: Because people are talking about the more elegant, faster and cross-browser way of doing something, and having to load jQuery to achieve it, is not an answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can change the `innerHTML` or `outerHTML` of an element on the page instead.

Comment: Preferably innerHTML, as outerHTML isn't widely supported.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not particularly great at JavaScript or its best practices, but `document.write()` along with `innerHtml()` basically allows you to write out strings that *may or may not* be valid HTML; it's just characters. By using the DOM, you ensure proper, standards-compliant HTML that will keep your page from breaking via plainly bad HTML.

And, as Tom mentioned, JavaScript is done after the page is loaded; it'd probably be a better practice to have the initial setup for your page to be done via standard HTML (via .html files  or whatever your server does [i.e. php]).

Comment: If you write dynamic components using javascript you will end up writing to DOM with javascript. While document.write() isn't really the way to go you will probably use innerHTML in most cases. Since innerHTML is a lot faster then using createNode/appendChild in all browsers. It's quite important when you have to generate a lot html/DOM elements. + it's document, not documment ;)

Answer (score 3):

`element.InnerHtml= allmycontent`: will re-write everything inside the element. You must use a variable `let allmycontent="this is what I want to print inside this element"`to store the whole content you want inside this element. If not each time you will call this function, the content of your element will be erased and replace with the last call you made of it.

`document.write()`: can be use several times, each time the content will be printed where the call is made on the page.

But be aware: **document.write()** method is **only** useful for inserting content at page creation . So use it for not repeating when having a lot of data to write like a catalogue of products or images.

Here a simple example: *all your li for your aside menu are stored in an array "tab", you can create a js script with the script tag directly into the html page and then use the write method in an iterative function where you want to insert those li on the page.*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write("<ul>");
for (var i=0; i<=tab.length; i++){
    document.write(tab[i]);
    }document.write("</ul>");
</script>`
```

This works because Js is **interpreted in a linear way** during the loading. So make sure your script is at the right place in your html page.You can also use an external Js file, but then again you must declare it at the place where you want it to be interpreted.

For this reason, **document.write** cannot be called for writing something on your page as a result of a **"user interaction"** (like click or hover), because then the DOM has been created and write method will, like said above, write a new page (purge the actual execution stack and start a new stack and a new DOM tree). In this case use:

```
element.innerHTML=("Myfullcontent");
```

To learn more about document's methods: open your console: `document;`
then open: `__proto__: HTMLDocumentPrototype`

You'll see the function property "write" in the document object.
You can also use **document.writeln** which add a new line at each statement.
To learn more about a function/method, just write its name into the console with no parenthesis: `document.write;`
The console will return a description instead of calling it.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to write html with JavaScript.

document.write is only useful when you want to write to page before it has actually loaded. If you use document.write() after the page has loaded (at onload event) it will create new page and overwrite the old content. Also it doesn't work with XML, that includes XHTML.

From other hand other methods can't be used before DOM has been created (page loaded), because they work directly with DOM.

These methods are:

- node.innerHTML = "Whatever";
- document.createElement('div'); and node.appendChild(), etc..

In most cases node.innerHTML is better since it's faster then DOM functions. Most of the time it also make code more readable and smaller.

Answer (score 1):

Surely the best way is to avoid doing any heavy HTML *creation* in your JavaScript at all? The markup sent down from the server ought to contain the bulk of it, which you can then manipulate, using CSS rather than brute force removing/replacing elements, if at all possible.

This doesn't apply if you're doing something "clever" like emulating a widget system.

Answer (score 0):

The document.write method is very limited. You can only use it before the page has finished loading. You can't use it to update the contents of a loaded page.

What you probably want is [innerHTML](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascript-innerHTML.php).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use, instead of `document.write`, DOM JavaScript API like `document.createElement`, `.createTextNode`, `.appendChild` and similar. Safe and almost cross browser.

[ihunger's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1533601) `outerHTML` is not cross browser, it's IE only.

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery, look how easy it is:

```
    var a = '<h1> this is some html </h1>';
    $("#results").html(a);

       //html
    <div id="results"> </div>
```