# Display a counter variable with JS

Tags: javascript

I have a rotating slide show I'm working on that uses Javascript.  I use a counter in the function, and I want to display the value of the counter each time the image changes. (so it will say "viewing i of x pictures")

I tried using

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">document.write(i);</script>
```

but it only displays the value of i when the page loads, and it won't update each time i increases.  Is there something better than document.write(i) that will update each time i increases or decreases?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the correct way to write HTML using Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533568/what-is-the-correct-way-to-write-html-using-javascript) And apart from using DOM methods, as specified in the answers of the linked question, the `language` attribute of the `script` element has been [deprecated](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/scripts.html#edef-SCRIPT).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wrap the value in a div or span or something similar and include an id attribute.  When the image changes, increment i and update the document.getElementById('dividhere').innerHTML with i

Answer (score 4):

In your HTML, instead of the above `SCRIPT` tag have something like this:

```
<div id="counter"></div>
```

In your Javascript function where the counter value updates, have the following line:

```
document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = i;
```