# Changing the content of meta refresh does not change refreshing time

Tags: javascript, html, meta-tags, meta

I have a `meta http-equiv="refresh"` inside the `<head>`.

```
<head>
     <meta name="mymeta" http-equiv="refresh" content="2" id="myMeta">
</head>
```

Using **Javascript**, I'm trying to change the `content` attribute of this `meta` tag.

```
var myMeta = document.getElementById("myMeta");
myMeta.content="10";
```

When I display the content via `document.write(myMeta.content);`, I get the changed value which is **10**, however, the `meta` tag will keep refreshing each **2** seconds.

I have tested this both in Firefox and Opera.

**FULL PAGE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="mymeta" http-equiv="refresh" content="2" id="myMeta">
<script>
var myMeta=document.getElementById("myMeta");
myMeta.content="10";
document.write(myMeta.content);
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think `meta` tags are "executed" only when loading the page. Adding / removing / changing them afterwards is ignored.

Comment: The following page explains each of the 4 methods, **Sets or returns..**, however I don't know why refreshing time isn't changing, even though the `content` is changing. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_meta.asp

Comment: It's easy to test, just remove the whole tag programmatically, and you'll find out, if your page will still have a timed refresh.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens because the browser immediately process the `<meta>` tag when it is present onload.

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fHYbH/).

When the document is being loaded, the browser sees and processes the following:

```
<meta name="mymeta" http-equiv="refresh" content="2" id="myMeta"/>
```

Even though you try to change its content from 2 to 10, that 2 second refresh is already acknowledged and the browser waits for 2 seconds before it refreshes the page. The 10-second refresh that is injected by JavaScript actually works*, although the page has been refreshed by the time it reaches 2 seconds and nothing seems to happen. This process is then repeated again and again.

Try the [opposite](http://jsfiddle.net/pjamy/) and see what happens.

<sup>*This only works on Safari and Chrome. Firefox and Opera does not support the modification of meta refresh through JavaScript.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The `getElementsByTagName` method returns a `NodeList` so you need to specify an index to correctly access the element:

```
 var myMeta = document.getElementsByTagName("meta")[0];
```

As someone mentioned this will probably still not work as the `meta` tag will need to be re-appended to have the desired effect.

Since you're using JavaScript you can just use `setTimeout` to achieve the same behavior

```
setTimeout(function() {
    location.reload();
},2000); // reload page after 2 seconds
```

Comment: True, but still I'm facing the same issue, refreshing time is not changed.