# string.fromcharcode javascript not working

Tags: javascript, string

I'm having trouble using string.fromcharcode on my url which is "http://www.google.com".

```
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=http://www.google.com">
```

If i try:

```
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=String.fromCharCode(104, 116, 116, 112, 58, 47, 47, 119, 119, 119, 46, 103, 111, 111, 103, 108, 101, 46, 99, 111, 109)">
```

It doesn't work.
//Edit
Then if i can't use string.fromcharcode what else can i do to encode my url?

Comment: You can't put javascript in the `content` tag like that.

Comment: [Works fine here](http://jsfiddle.net/apPX3/) - your problem is somewhere else

Comment: What makes you thing that if you dump JavaScript code in there it will be executed?

Comment: Probably won't work even if attempted properly; possible duplicate of [Changing the content of meta refresh does not change refreshing time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790065/changing-the-content-of-meta-refresh-does-not-change-refreshing-time)

Comment: As an aside, this is the kind of code I *hate*. An instant redirect to a url that is obfuscated? What are you trying to do here, and why are you trying to hide it. Create something people want to use.

Comment: Adam, i'm having trouble using http: or //, it gets formatted as a url, so i need to obfuscate it to avoid that.

Comment: It *is* a url - why is that a problem?

Comment: You don't understand, because it gets formatted as a url, it does not execute, instead it remains visual.

Comment: It sounds like you're putting this in the `body` of the page - it needs to go in the `head`. Then it will execute and you won't need to obfuscate it.

Comment: Your behaviour towards those trying to help you is not welcome here. **EDIT** @user2489256 wrote a *very* abusive comment towards me, and has now removed it.

Answer (score 1):

This belongs in a `script`-tag, since it is Javascript.
Reference: [String.fromCharCode()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode)
e.g.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    string=String.fromCharCode(65,72,65)
    console.log(string)
</script>
```

Perhaps you want to use [location.href](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.location) to refer to another website.