# innerHTML not working on node

Tags: javascript, dom

In my script `node1.data` & `node1.textContent` are working perfectly but `node1.innerHTML` is not displaying anything, and I'm not getting why.

```
var text = [];
function getN(node1) {
    textNodesUnder(node1, text);
    return text.join("");
}
function textNodesUnder(node1, text) {
    if (node1.nodeType == 3) {
        text.push(node1.innerHTML);
        document.write(node1.textContent + "<br>");
    }
    var children = node1.childNodes;
    for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        textNodesUnder(children[i], text);
    }
}
```

and

```
<body onload="alert('The document content is ' + getN(document))" >
```

Comment: Do not use document write

Answer (score 1):

At that point `node1` is a reference to the `document` object. Which indeed does not have the `innerHTML` property

Answer (score 0):

try `document.body.innerHTML` as it will give the element that has the inner HTML elements

Answer (score 0):

The `Element.innerHTML` property sets or gets the HTML syntax describing the element's descendants.
**Example**

`document.getElementById("some_element").innerHTML="JavaScript"; //innerHTML is property of element not document`

[MDN - innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

Useful information regarding [JavaScript-innerHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10826756/javascript-innerhtml-not-working)