# How to take JS string and show it in HTML5 as preview?

Tags: javascript, string, html, html5-canvas

I am quite new to both HTML5 and Javascript. I want to set an editable string in Javascript which will hold HTML5 code so it can be edited from Javascipt interface. Then I want to take this string to another HTML5 page and show it as a preview. So that the string edited in Javascript interface will be seen as a result right next to it in a small HTML5 preview screen.

How to refer to the string in JS script from HTML5 and use it as if it is a part of HTML5 code?

Hope I could explain myself.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert HTML dynamically using jQuery. Check out this example for more info: [What is the correct way to write HTML using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533568/what-is-the-correct-way-to-write-html-using-javascript)

I'm sorry if this isn't what you're asking. I'm not sure I fully understand the question. Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for response.
what document.write() does is this:

<script>
document.write("Hello World!");
</script>

so you see the text on the screen and you can take a string or any text from other script or document. but I want to do this:

<script>
document.write(<!DOCTYPE html><head>...);
</script>

so it wont show as text but as html5 code. I dont think so but can document.write() do this?

Comment: Sorry, I misread the linked response.  If you check the answer on the post I linked, he shows how to use jQuery to add dynamic html to a specific node in the DOM. Are you asking how to have an html preview of a different page on the same page? Also, I'll update my answer so it isn't as confusing.

Comment: Yes this is what I want. I'm sorry, guess I was distracted, couldn't understand the use of document.write(). Now I get it. Here is an example of how I want to use it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write Thanks!