# How to document.write to parent element when external javascript called

Tags: javascript, html, domdocument

Hello my question is how to write inside script called parent element with `document.write` when parent element is unknown

You may consider this as advertising script

For example:

```
<div>
<script src="http://www.pokemonpets.com/scripts/ads_simple.js"></script>
</div>
```

My script code below but not working right now

```
document.write('<a title="Bedava Pokemon Online Oyunu" target="_blank" href="http://www.pokemonpets.com/Register"><img src="http://orig04.deviantart.net/58d0/f/2015/213/8/4/pokemonpets_by_monstermmorpg-d93plr1.png" /></a>');
```

So somehow i have to make it work without knowing parent element or without knowing whether page has JQuery or not.

How does advertising companies handle this?

Comment: Please define "not working". FYI, `document.write` isn't aware of "parent element", it just writes immediately after the script tag where a code calls it.

Comment: Seems to work fine here: http://jsbin.com/wisatanefu/1/edit?html,output

Comment: Don't use [document.write](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice).

Comment: @Quentin it turns out the page i tried was not working you are right :D

Comment: @shortnamed what can i use?

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG you can use `Node.innerHTML` or use `document.createElement`, `document.createTextNode` and `Node.appendChild`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533568/what-is-the-correct-way-to-write-html-using-javascript

Comment: @shortnamed OP says: "parent element is unknown" ... How to get `Node`?

Comment: @Teemu `Node.parentElement`?

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use document.write, you want to find your script tag and replace it with your new content.  You can do that by looking for a script tag with your URL, then having it's parent replace it.

```
scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
for(var i in scripts){
   if(scripts[i].src.indexOf('//www.pokemonpets.com/scripts/ads_simple.js') !== -1){
      var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
      wrapper.innerHTML = '<a title="Bedava Pokemon Online Oyunu" target="_blank" href="http://www.pokemonpets.com/Register"><img src="http://orig04.deviantart.net/58d0/f/2015/213/8/4/pokemonpets_by_monstermmorpg-d93plr1.png" /></a>';
      scripts[i].parentElement.replaceChild(wrapper,scripts[i]);
   }
}
```

This is totally untested, not even for syntax, so you might need to fiddle with it a bit.