# javascript document element by id

Tags: javascript

If I need to see my out put in the page not in console.log i want use document get Element By Id how can i do that? he gave me just one result, Steve only !!

[Code: ]
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISqzT.png

```js
<script>
    var friends = {};
    friends.bill = {
      firstName: "Bill",
      lastName: "Gates",
      number: "(206) 555-5555",
      address: ['Microsoft Way']
      };
    friends.steve = {
      firstName: "Steve",
      lastName: "Jobes",
      number: "(444) 111 000",
      address: ["Apple way"]
    };
    var list = function(obj) {
      for( var key in obj){
        console.log(obj);
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = key + "<br>";
      }
    }

    var search = function(name) {
      for(var key in friends){
        if(name === friends[key].firstName){
          console.log(friends[key]);
        }
      }
    }
    list(friends);
    // search("Steve");
  </script>
```

Comment: You keep overwriting the contents, what did you expect?

Comment: What output? Where do you want to direct the output to?

Comment: Step through the code in a debugger and watch what happens to `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML` each time the loop runs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the correct way to write HTML using Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533568/what-is-the-correct-way-to-write-html-using-javascript)

Comment: document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += key + "<br>"; you have to add the key and not overwrite it '+='

Answer (score 1):

Hey the only change you have to make is using += instead of just = for the innerHTML function.  Here you go:

text.innerHTML+=friend + "
";

Comment: in the same example if i'm doing like that?
var search = function(name) {
      for(var key in friends){
        if(name === friends[key].firstName){
          console.log(friends[key]);
          document.getElementById('search').innerHTML += friends[key] + "<br>";
        }
      }
    }
output will be [object Object] how can i fix that??

Answer (score 0):

Simply append the result to your innerHTML, do not overwrite it, likewise:
`document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += key + "<br>";`

Comment: Pedro Gonçalves
isn't work
Can you gave me the code?