# How to define a value from javascript in html

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I am in trouble in my project.

When my page is loded, I need to define a value from DB with ajax to A[] in my html web code.

The DB SQL is:

```
<?php
includes("DB.php");//for connecting and log on DB
select count(*) as total from  OA where  handleP='John' and stat='suspending';
?>
```

The total maybe is 0,or 1, or others;

So A[] maybe is A[0], or maybe A[1], or others.

A[] default value is A[0]. How to define it?

Here is html code:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="easyui-linkbutton" onclick="standbyDoc()">A[0]</a><br />
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the correct way to write HTML using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533568/what-is-the-correct-way-to-write-html-using-javascript)

Comment: Use `document.write()`, `.createTextNode()` or `.innerHTML` depending on your needs.

Comment: @ObsidianAge, please see my update. Thankyou for your kindly hearted

Comment: @ObsidianAge, my question is different from What is the correct way to write HTML using Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

As @ObsidianAge said, it depends on your needs. If your real case is as simple as provided code, you can get necessary HTML element and use `innerHTML` (for example). It should be something like this:

```js
var A = ['test'];
document.getElementsByClassName("easyui-linkbutton")[0].innerHTML = A[0];
```

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="easyui-linkbutton" onclick="standbyDoc()">A[0]</a><br />
```

Comment: Thankyou. I use php code in html for fetching total data directly

Comment: @Snow, sorry, I'm not familiar with PHP