# How to populate a div from the data from fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am getting my output in a react app at `this.state` but I want to bring this outside and populate div so that I can show it at the frontend. How can I do it?

```js
 fetch("https://flask-api-test1.herokuapp.com/predict", {
      method: "post",
      body: formData,
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(state);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
```

[image: output from the api]

Comment: It would make it easier to help you if you shared the complete component you're having trouble with.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/1533650

Answer (score 1):

Your example is a bit incomplete. Anyways, here is how I would do that if the returned data was an array
https://codesandbox.io/s/mutable-leftpad-o3v30?file=/src/App.js

Comment: when I am passing fetchData to an h1 or div tag then I am getting this error. ```react-dom.development.js:13231 Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {result}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.```

Comment: I have attached the pic from the API output from console.log(data) @aetheode

Comment: Updated that code on codesandbox (https://codesandbox.io/s/mutable-leftpad-o3v30?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 1):

If you can use hooks then the simplest solution is useState

```
import {useState} from 'react'
```

declare

```
const [newState, setNewState] = useState()
```

then you try

```
 fetch("https://flask-api-test1.herokuapp.com/predict", {
      method: "post",
      body: formData,
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((result) => {
        setNewState(result)
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
```

and you can use ready-made 'newState' for div in jsx like

```
<div>
 {newState?.keyDataYouNeed}
</div>
```

Comment: ```react-dom.development.js:13231 Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {result}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.``` I am getting this error

Comment: ```result:
predictions: -3.5411367416381836
[[Prototype]]: Object
[[Prototype]]: Object``` This is my output from console.log(data)

Comment: Why guys keep assigning values like this, `this.state = result;` THATS HUGH WRONG, do this, `setNewState(result)` man, clearly hes not using react hooks,

Comment: @AshishKamble Yes, I have removed `this.state = result`; and I am using useState

Comment: @harsh "Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child" you get this error because in the "result" you have an object, and the react cannot simply display it as well as the console.log 
if if you need to see in the console try ```console.log(JSON.stringify(newState.result))```
if if you need to get predictions from result in JSX try 
```<div>
 {newState?.result?.predictions}
</div>```

Answer (score 0):

never do `this.state` and assign values directly, as its immutable,
what you can do is ,

```
fetch("https://flask-api-test1.herokuapp.com/predict", {
  method: "post",
  body: formData,
})
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((result) => {
    this.setState({data:result});
    console.log(result);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```